# imap_search and FROM criteria

Tags: php, imap

Is it possible to have multiple FROM criterias declared?

I've tryed:

```
$emails = imap_search($imap, 'FROM "test@stackoverflow.com" FROM2 "test2@stackoverflow.com"');
```

and

```
$emails = imap_search($imap, 'FROM "test@stackoverflow.com,test2@stackoverflow.com"');
```

and

```
$emails = imap_search($imap, 'FROM "test@stackoverflow.com" OR FROM "test2@stackoverflow.com"');
```

None of those works. Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used imap before, but you could try something like this?

```
$from = array("test@stackoverflow.com", "test2@stackoverflow.com");
$emails = array();

foreach($from as $search){
    $emails[] = imap_search($imap, 'FROM "'.$search.'"');
}
```

Comment: This really helped me figure it out: http://www.limilabs.com/blog/imap-search-requires-parentheses

Comment: @RobR. So did you get it to work using the polish notation ?

Answer (score 2):

IMAP Search's OR syntax is a little funny. Normally we think like this:

```
A OR B OR C
```

In IMAP, on the other hand, it works like this:

```
OR OR A B C
```

You should read it like this:

```
OR( OR(A B) )
```

It's really a [prefix notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).

So, to answer your question directly, you need to do something like this:

OR FROM "test@stackoverflow.com" FROM "test2@stackoverflow.com"

Not sure if the quotes are necessary.

Comment: Without quotes, php throws T_LOGICAL_OR error. It doesn't work either way.

Comment: I mean the inner quotes around the email addresses. Of course you need quotes to put the whole thing in a string.

Comment: In my case, I'm using SUBJECT and BODY phrases with spaces and so I need to use quotes.

Comment: How about putting the entire criteria in single quotes? Wouldn't that work?!!

Comment: I don't think so. It's been a while and I don't remember the details, but my guess is that will result in either (a) IMAP taking the whole thing as one big literal string (rather than statements separated by logical operators), or (b) you'll get a syntax error because it expects literals to use double quotes rather than single quotes.

Answer (score -1):

```
$emails = imap_search($connection, OR FROM "@domain.pt"  FROM "user@any_domain.pt" );
```

This will filter only mails received from any user od domain.pt and from user user@any_domain.pt

Worked for me, hope it'll work for you.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.